# Carbon setTestNow function is not working

Tags: laravel-5.6, php-carbon

I am working on dates in Laravel. I have to set dates for patient future injections.
To keep it simple, let's suppose today is 13-03-2019 (Wednesday).
I created first date as:

```
$firstDate = Carbon::create(2019,03 ,18, 12); // The day is Monday
// set date
Carbon::setTestNow($firstDate);
```

Now I want the next two appointments should be on Wednesday and Friday. So I again set the dates as follow:

```
  // set second date
   $secondDate = new Carbon('Wednesday');
   Carbon::setTestNow($secondDate); 
   // set thirdDate
   $thirdDate = new Carbon('Friday');
   Carbon::setTestNow($thirdDate);
```

According to above example the output should be:

1. 2019-03-18
2. 2019-03-20
3. 2019-03-22

But the problem is that it outputs the first set date correct but print the 2nd and 3rd date wrong as it considers 'Wednesday' of next week as today's date.
So the Output print as:

1. 2019-03-18
2. 2019-03-13
3. 2019-03-14

I have spent a lot of time on it, I would appreciate if anyone of you people could help me in this.
I would appreciate if anyone guides me where I am going wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the setTestNow() function was not working for 2nd and third date/days, so I first get all three required days then convert them to 'dayOfWeek' which returns day number (Sunday 0, Monday 1 and so on...). I subtracted the first day from second and third day and then finally add these days to the date that i get from the datepicker.

```
      // set the start date
      if( $visitstart_date != null && $visitstart_date != '') {
           Carbon::setTestNow($visitstart_date);
      } else {
       Carbon::setTestNow(); 
     }

     if($perweek_visit1_day != '')
     {  
        //Get first selected day number
        $firstDay = Carbon::parse($perweek_visit1_day)->dayOfWeek;
        $perweek_visit1_dayDate = Carbon::now();
     }
     if($perweek_visit2_day != '')
     {  
        //Get second day numer
        $secondDay = Carbon::parse($perweek_visit2_day)->dayOfWeek - $firstDay;
        $perweek_visit2_dayDate = Carbon::now()->addDays($secondDay);
      }
     if($perweek_visit3_day != '')
     {  
        //Get third day number
        $thirdDay = Carbon::parse($perweek_visit3_day)->dayOfWeek - $firstDay;
        $perweek_visit3_dayDate = Carbon::now()->addDays($thirdDay);
     }
```